# Redactor formatting buttons - IE compatibility

Tags: redactor

In IE, if you use the formatting buttons (bold, italics, underlines) using the toolbar, or via ctrl+b, ctrl+i, or ctrl+u, formatting does not take effect when you subsequently type. The only way to format text in IE is to highlight text, and then use the toolbar buttons, or key combinations, to format that existing highlighted text. (without modification)

Are there any modifications that anyone has made or could make to fix this?

Obviously it is not intended and this issue does not occur in Chrome, not sure about Firefox.